# Far OTM calculation issue on Bjerksund-Stensland

Tags: options, american-options

Has anyone come across and fixed calculation issues on boundaries using Bjerksund-Stensland 2002 (Hull, Haug or Rouah implementations) ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about the early exercise boundary (B0 and B_inf)? The B0 boundary can be questionable when cost of carry is the same as risk free rate (r=b for options on non dividend-paying equity underlier). If cost of carry equals risk free rate, I will have to assume a small value for r-b to get the boundary B0.

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/30824897.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Put more simply, and considering current market variables (b>r), a SPY Put Credit Spread will be modelled incorrectly most likely due to B0.